# Selecting heirarchical data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchical

I have this table (followers) in my database.

```
follower | following
---------|----------
1        |2
1        |4
1        |5
1        |6
1        |7
1        |8
2        |4
4        |6
```

This documents all of the followings and followers for my users. I have this query, which is not working.

```
SELECT following 
FROM followers 
WHERE follower 
IN (SELECT following 
    FROM followers 
    WHERE follower = 2) 
OR following IN (SELECT follower 
                 FROM followers 
                 WHERE following = 2)
```

What I am trying to achieve is a list of users followed by the users that the user "2" follows, merged with a list of users that follow the user "2". Excluding everyone already being followed by user "2". And arranged by how closely related to the user "2" they are.

Ideally, my data output would be this (but not automatically that order):

```
suggested_users
---------------
6
1
5
7
8
```

I am actually at a loss as to how to ask this question, but how do I get these results?

Comment: As MySQL does not support recursive queries, the only way to do this is to write a stored procedure.

Comment: Darn. I'll take a look at that, then >:(

Comment: You can always upgrade to Postgres where this is a piece of cake (with a single statement)

Comment: What is the statement with Postgres? I might switch, MySQL seems a little soft :P

Comment: @ProbabilityWolf: I'll edit my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it's an option for you to dump mysql, some sql variants let you get the tree using a recursive query:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

If not, there are a variety of solutions; typically nested sets or nested intervals:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals

(There are many questions on SO related to both.)

---

> What is the statement with Postgres? I might switch, MySQL seems a little soft :P

Untested, but it's something like:

```
with recursive tree (root, node) as (
select following as root, follower as node
  from followers
union all
select tree.root, followers.follower
  from followers
  join tree on tree.node = followers.following
)
select * from tree where root = 2;
```

And the optimized version would be like:

```
with recursive tree (root, node) as (
select following as root, follower as node
  from followers
 where following = 2
union all
select tree.root, followers.follower
  from followers
  join tree on tree.node = followers.following
)
select * from tree;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by joining the `followers` table on itself.

Try this:

```
SELECT f2.following suggested_users
FROM followers f1
INNER JOIN followers f2 ON f2.follower = f1.following
WHERE f1.follower = 2
GROUP BY f2.following

UNION

SELECT f3.follower suggested_users
FROM followers f3
WHERE f3.following = 2
GROUP BY f3.follower
```

The general idea of this query is that:

1. `f1.follower` follows `f1.following` and `f1.following = f2.follower`
2. `f2.follower` follows `f2.following`

combined with

1. `f3.follower` follows `f3.following` and `f3.following = 2`

The table joins will look like this:

**First sub-query**

```
f1.follower | f1.following = f2.follower | f2.following | suggested_users |
------------|----------------------------|--------------|-----------------|
2           |4                           |6             | 6               |
```

**Second sub-query**

```
f3.follower | f3.following | suggested_users |
------------|--------------|-----------------|
1           |2             |1                |
```

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals not for identifiers.